# Obtaining word polarity in each review

Tags: keras, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I'm working on a domain-specific sentiment analysis, and I want to get each independent word polarity in that specific corpus (not a general score like "SentiWordNet" or other lexicons).

At first I thought using the following formula would help:

```
positive_word_polarity = # word occurrence in positive reviews / # all words in pos and neg reviews
```

```
negative_word_polarity = # word occurrence in negative reviews / # all words in pos and neg reviews
```

but then I found some issues regarding to this solution:

1. We have "good" in positive review and negative review "negative review".
2. There might be some words with a lot of occurrences but lower effect or vice versa.

So basically my inputs are reviews and their polarities and I need a lexicon containing words and their polarities.

Answer (score 0):

To solve problem `2)` you can multiply your polarity formulae with tfidf

[image]

> The inverse document frequency is a measure of how much information
>   the word provides, i.e., if it's common or rare across all documents.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf